# Overlay SpatialPointsDataFrame and a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame when the number of rows is unequal

Tags: r, overlay, polygon, spatial, points

I am wondering if this is possible in R.

I have a SpatialPointsDataFrame, which includes points that have attributes assigned to them. I want to overlay this SpatialPointsDataFrame with a SpatialPolygonDataFrame. Below is the code I am using. Just to clarify both the polygon and point data frame are in the same projected coordinated system.

```
buptpol <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(bu_proj_poly, bu.pts)
```

When I execute the code, I get the following error message:

```
Error in stopifnot(length(Sr@polygons) == nrow(data)) : 
  no slot of name "polygons" for this object of class "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
```

The issue is that the length of polygon file exceeds the row in the points file. Is there any way to overlay the points onto the polygon file in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Overlaying is done using the `over` function, not using `SpatialPolygonDataFrame`. For more details, please see the documentation of `over`.

Comment: +1 I was going to suggest sharing an example, but that would just be copy/paste from the docs!

Comment: Thanks I found the solution!!!